# Weird spike and steady state in loss function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions

I have trained a CNN based pose estimation network that outputs segmentation masks and keypoints. I have used Adam optimizer, 1e-4 learning rate and [cyclical learning rate scheduler](https://github.com/bckenstler/CLR). As shown on figure, on 40th epoch there is a extreme spike and then there occurs a steady state loss for all epochs. What could have caused this?
[image]

Comment: can you show the lr schedule too?

Comment: In fact, I did not save learning rate history but I check logs after training and learning rate was as it should be.

Comment: As I have investigated model I understood that it is dead ReLU problem and solved as removing ReLU from last layer.